# database file doesn't appear in my explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I follow this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but in the end I can't find out where the School.sdf in the Solution Explorer although everything works fine.

I rewrite my connection string exactly the same as the one written in the tutorial

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString ="data source=|DataDirectory|School.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"    />
         <!-->="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
         -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Click on button 'Show All Files' in the top of Solution Explorer

Comment: I did, but that file doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2):

you can click " show all files" on the top of solution show all files, then if you can see the school.sdf file, then you can right click the school.sdf file，choice included in the project

Comment: Also note that the Data Directory is the App_Data folder, and if your application code is actually creating the database, it's not going to show up until after you run the part in the app that creates it.